# How many 5 digit numbers can be obtained using digits 0,2,9 at least once?

Tags: combinatorics

This was my approach:
Total numbers that can be formed from 0, 2, 9 will be=2×3×3×3×3=162

Out of these;
Numbers with only 0, 9= 1×2×2×2×2= 16

Numbers with only0, 2= 1×2×2×2×2= 16

Numbers with only 9, 2=
2×2×2×2×2= 32

Numbers with only 2=1
Numbers with only 9=1

Thus the answer I got=162-16-16-32-2= 96

However, in my textbook the answer given is 100.

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: You are taking away from 162 the numbers 99999 and 22222 more than you should. You take it out three times each, so its a -6, but you should only take it out once each, so you are taking away a -4 extra, which is what you are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is while considering the cases, you haven't taken 'at least once'. That is, your approach would have been better if you counted all permutations with 0,2 at least once, rather than all together.

While counting numbers with 0,2 the case 22222 arises, similarly with 0,9 the case 99999 is counted. And also when you count 2,9 both cases arise once again. Here as you are counting them extra, they must be added.

Hence, the correct calculation will be  162-16-16-32+2=100

Comment: Ohh.. I realised my mistake now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help :-)